# Disable form after business hours

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a form for a delivery company who isn't a 24 hour operation, which means I would like the form to redirect to a new page or alert with the company hours when a user submits the form during off-hours.

For example, say the company's hours are from 9am to 9pm and a customer fills out the form requesting a delivery at 9:15pm. Instead of having the form submitted and the customer redirected to a thank you page after he hits submit, I would like them redirected to a different page or alerted that the business is closed until 9am or something along those lines.

Is this possible to do using jQuery?

Comment: Answer **Yes** It's possible. Are you trying any solution or just ask?

Comment: Just be careful with timezones.

Comment: Ive googled and googled but havent found a solutuion, like I said Im by no means a coder so any help is greatly appreciated. Im not too worried about timezones as its a very local delivery business that stays within city boundaries.

Comment: This would be better server side, as you can't guarantee a user has their clock set correctly.

Comment: Don't worry to much about time zones, just absolutely make sure you are using your server's time and *not* make the beginners fault of using the client's time with `new Date()` or something. I've recently seen this error made by a large food delivery service when I was accessing their site with an old machine with broken clock battery. No pizza for me.

Comment: I have to say, a company I use often has a feature like this and it pisses me off to no end. I would strongly suggest you include a message to say when your office hours are, but allow users to submit at any time and just put them in a queue.

Comment: What Kolink said - the beauty and strength of web-based services like this is that they don't work to business hours. I think your form should not offer delivery slots outside of the available hours - that way, if the user is filling in the form out of hours, the next available slots are the following morning.

Comment: You should use server code, because it's depend on timezone!!!

Comment: Thanks guys. Its actually an alcohol & fast food delivery service I'm doing for friends and they don't want after hours orders queued until the a.m. because the customers often don't remember ordering come morning.
 I was just looking to get the submit button to redirect to a "Sorry, we're closed" page from 12am to 8am everyday instead of a thank you page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done using `jQuery` but i prefer `server-side` scripting because as you know `client-side` code can be `disabled` by user so check it on `server-side` and then use `redirection` feature to take user wherever you want.